# How do I show the results of my [Django] model in [HTML] from a [PostgreSQL] database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, psycopg2

I am developing a web application with Django and PostgreSQL support. I am using Psycopg2 to connect with my PostgreSQL database. I am attempting to list all of the tables in my database on my Home.html document.

I am having trouble showing this in the Home.html document. Below I have included my code.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import psycopg2


# Create your models here.def __init__(self, db='giquery-data'):

class Tables(models.Model):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='giquery-data' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='admin'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # """SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='public'"""
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='public'")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Tables
from django.template import loader

# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    all_tables = Tables.rows
    template = loader.get_template('tablesearch/home.html')
    context = {
        'all_tables': all_tables
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

**Home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    {% for rows in all_tables %}
    <li>
         {{ rows.table_catalog }} - {{ rows.table_name }} Test
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Currently, my results look like:

[image]

How can I show the names of the database tables on Home.html?

Comment: What is in `all_tables` when you run the same code from a python shell?

Comment: @JohnGordon-  When I run "rows" I get:

>>>rows
[('giquery-data', 'public', 'spatial_ref_sys', 'BASE TABLE', None, None, None, None, None, 'YES', 'NO', None), ('giquery-data', 'public', 'address_pt', 'BASE TABLE', None, None, None, None, None, 'YES', 'NO', None), ('giquery-data', 'public', 'buildings', 'BASE TABLE', None, None, None, None, None, 'YES', 'NO', None), ('giquery-data', 'public', 'precincts', 'BASE TABLE', None, None, None, None, None, 'YES', 'NO', None), ('giquery-data', 'public', 'streets', 'BASE TABLE', None, None, None, None, None, 'YES', 'NO', None)]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is your use case and why you can't use django admin?

Comment: @Angela I want to use this web app to list all table in my database on one page, then allow users to click on it and preview the data in thoe tables. On another page I want users to be able to query the data in the database. I was using Psycopg2 because I want to be able to continuously add tables to the database without going through the hastle of making models for each new table.

Comment: Those values look like plain tuples, and you can't access tuple elements via attribute names such as `rows.table_name`.  Try accessing the values by numeric index instead: `{{ rows.2 }}` (or whatever that column number is.)

Comment: @JohnGordon SOLUTION! -- Thank you! I have been working on this problem for hours!

Comment: Great!  I'll post it as an answer.  Please click on the checkmark to accept it :-)

Comment: @JohnGordon Accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those values look like plain tuples, and you can't access tuple elements via attribute names such as `rows.table_name`. Try accessing the values by numeric index instead: `{{ rows.2 }}` (or whatever that column number is.)